# joomla K2 how to load extra fields inside item body

Tags: php, joomla, joomla-k2

How can I load extra fields/groups inside of a tab which is inside of an item?

is there any way to load them akin to `{loadposition extra-fields-group-name}`, or anything else along these lines?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

K2 is very badly documented for developers. In fact, it's undocumented.

K2 works on templates. You need to copy the template based on what you want access to like K2 Items or K2 Category. If the Extra Fields are accessible easily through K2 Items, than this is what you want to use.

Perhaps some day someone will create a software developers guide to K2, but for now, it's mostly do what I said above and using print_r and var_dump to figure out what is coming from where. The developer from K2 has a bad attitude, if you post anything against K2, he jumps all over you and tells you it's free software.

Answer (score 3):

you can do like this

```
<?php echo $item->extraFields->EXTRA_FIELD_ALIAS_HERE->value; ?>
```